# Why is my Funq container not working properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I'm getting a null reference exception when hitting my code that tries to access the database.

This is in global.asax and I have stepped through the debugger and this code is being executed.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public class DmsAppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public DmsAppHost() : base("API", typeof(AppUsersService).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            var dbConnectionFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=dms; Password=dms; Database=dms", PostgreSqlDialect.Provider);
            container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbConnectionFactory);
            container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<AppUserRepository, IAppUserRepository>();
        }
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        new DmsAppHost().Init();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BootstrapSupport.BootstrapBundleConfig.RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

}
```

When I hit this code (using (var db = DbConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())) I am getting a NullReferenceException.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
public class AppUserRepository : IAppUserRepository
{
    public IDbConnectionFactory DbConnectionFactory { get; set; }

    public AppUser GetAppUserByUsername(string username)
    {
        AppUser appUser;
        using (var db = DbConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            appUser = db.QuerySingle<AppUser>(new { username });
        }
        return appUser;
    }
}
```

Am I to assume something is wrong with my Connection or is there something I'm not doing right to make Funq work?

Comment: I also tried this with SqlLite and get the same issue. It seems like Funq is not creating an instance of my DbConnectionFactory.

Comment: here you are calling `DbConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection()` I can't see where you are actually `Creating the Connection` am I overlooking something here

Comment: It is supposed to be handled by Funq (the IOC container) in the global.asax file above. At least that is how I understand it to work.

Comment: Could you update with your latest code example? It's difficult to tell where things are at now.

Comment: Is it because the IoC container only works with those instances that occur within a service and since I'm using it in a repository and not through a service then it's not working?

Comment: What does AppUsersService look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have shown some Funq container configuration that is injecting dependencies into your `AppUserRepository` class. But you haven't shown how and where is this class used. Since your question is tagged with `asp.net-mvc` I assume that this happens inside an ASP.NET MVC controller action. Something along the lines of:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    private readonly IAppUserRepository repo;
    public HomeController(IAppUserRepository repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var model = this.repo.Get(id);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

If you want to use a dependency injection framework in ASP.NET MVC you will have to write a custom [`dependency resolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.idependencyresolver%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) which will do the injection into the controllers.

So let's go ahead and write one for Funq:

```
public class FunqDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly ContainerResolveCache cache;
    public FunqDependencyResolver(Container container)
    {
        this.cache = new ContainerResolveCache(container);
        var controllerTypes =
            (from type in Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes()
             where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(type)
             select type).ToList();
        container.RegisterAutoWiredTypes(controllerTypes);
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.cache.CreateInstance(serviceType, true);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<object>();
    }
}
```

and then we could register it in `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    var container = new Container();
    var dbConnectionFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=dms; Password=dms; Database=dms", PostgreSqlDialect.Provider);
    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbConnectionFactory);
    container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<AppUserRepository, IAppUserRepository>();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new FunqDependencyResolver(container));

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BootstrapSupport.BootstrapBundleConfig.RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Also I would recommend you using constructor injection for your `AppUserRepository` class because the `DbConnectionFactory` is an absolutely required dependency for this class to work properly:

```
public class AppUserRepository : IAppUserRepository
{
    private readonly IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory;
    public class AppUserRepository(IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory)
    {
        this.dbConnectionFactory = dbConnectionFactory;
    }

    public AppUser GetAppUserByUsername(string username)
    {
        AppUser appUser;
        using (var db = this.dbConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            appUser = db.QuerySingle<AppUser>(new { username });
        }
        return appUser;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tell the container how to resolve `IAppUserRepository` with the following configuration.

`container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<AppUserRepository, IAppUserRepository>();`

`RegisterAutoWiredAs` will inject the `IDbConnectionFactory` dependency

Comment: I added that but when it hits to the code to AppUserRepository.GetAppUserByUsername("user") then I also get a null reference exception.

Comment: Is your dependency in the service against the interface or the concrete type?

Comment: I have this in the service public IAppUserRepository AppUserRepository { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing how your resolve `IAppUserRepository`, but with Funq you would have to do any project injection in your factory delegate instance when you register the abstraction.

See http://funq.codeplex.com/discussions/217686 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that `DbConnectionFactory` doesn't becomes an object so it is still null

it's like you would do this

```
public TextBlock nullBlock; // it's your public IDbConnectionFactory DbConnectionFactory { get; set; }
nullBlock.Text;             //           DbConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection()
```

you need to set an object

in your case something like

```
var obj = new AppUserRepository();
obj.DbConnectionFactory = .... //
```

additional if you fill it in some hidden code

you should do this and set a breakpoint maybe your overhanded object is null

```
private IDbConnectionFactory _dbConnectionFactory
public IDbConnectionFactory DbConnectionFactory 
{
      get {return _dbConnectionFactory; }
      set {_dbConnectionFactory=value;}
}
```